# Nuxt.js: Trigger client side script on page change

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a piece of client side script that is part of a static HTML template that builds the elements on the page on page load. It loads fine on initial app load, but when you navigate to a different page using the `nuxt-link` component it doesn't run the script again.

```
window.onNuxtReady((app) => {
  console.log('Nuxt ready!');
});
```

For now I am using the interval function to run the script every second, but it doesn't work fully.

```
setInterval(function(){
  mr.documentReady($); // A big function including a load a script, and jQuery is passed in.
}, 1000);
```

I've experienced this with Turbolinks on Rails apps, but there is the `.on('page:load',...` as a callback. Is there a similar callback to use client side for Nuxt?

The script in question is being loaded from the plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of beforeRouteEnter, beforeRouteUpdate , beforeRouteEnter

like link below:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to run the script client side. You gathered I'm trying to run a piece of client side script, not server side?